# How to use "under way"?

Tags: word-usage

Are the following 2 sentences correct?

1. Have the phone interviews gotten under way?
2. Have the phone interviews got under way?

My question is, is it correct to use "got/gotten" with "under way"?

Or should it be:
Are the phone interviews under way?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: You can say it any of those ways.  In AmE, "have gotten" is the preferred present perfect. Personally, I would use "are they underway" to ask if an interview is occurring _at this moment_, and "have gotten underway" to ask if the first one had begun (or finished), without regard to whether an interview is occurring _at this moment_. (As there are to be multiple interviews, they might be separated by considerable time.)

Answer (score 1):

'Have ... got underway' is wrong in any even semi-formal context. 'Have gotten underway' is idiomatic.

[Note that I only say this with certainty about American English.]

Comment: This is only true in American English

Comment: @TimLymington, okay. I looked around as a result of your comment, and it appears you're expressing a consensus. The question seems to have come up repeatedly on this forum, and it has received a variety of answers, including different answers from the same people. The problem for me is that the answers seem directed toward 'have got' with a possessive sense, and I'm not seeing that clear distinction between BrE and AmE for the "*have* of the perfect" (as Lawler puts it), which is what we have here.

Comment: You may be interested in this frequency comparison. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+under+way%2Care+underway%2Cgot+underway%2Cgotten+underway&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20under%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20underway%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20underway%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgotten%20underway%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *Gotten* is not idiomatic in British English, whatever the context. The OED says it is "rare, except in *ill-gotten*":  I myself, in quite a wide experience, have never seen it save as an Americanism or other dialect

Answer (score 0):

**Meaning from OED**:

> Having started and in progress; being done or carried out:

**Usage**:

> Have the phone interviews gotten under way? 
>   This is colloquial English
>
> Have the phone interviews got under way?
>   This is incorrect

**The right usage is:**

> Are the phone interviews under way?

**Usage examples from OED**:

> recruitment **is** well **under way**
>
> The project **is** already **under way**, with work due to be completed by early next year.
>
> At one end of this area, a massive building project **has been underway** for the best part of 20 years.
>
> The doctors' surgery will house five GPs, and moves **are underway** to recruit a sixth.